# need help in sum of time in rdlc

Tags: reporting, rdlc

I am working on attendance management system.
In my project i want to display total worked hours of the employee in the daily report.

In my database table i have already calculated working hours for the each employee.
Now i want to display Total worked hours of each and every entry at the bottom of the report.

e.g

```
EmployeeId EmployeeName  WorkedHours
1             ABC        04:00:25
2             XYZ        07:23:01
3             PQR        11:02:15
```

SO i want to display total of all 3 employees at the end of report in RDLC.

like **Total: 22:25:42**

Please let me know how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `=Sum(Fields!WorkedHours.Value)` in footer row for "WorkedHours" column.

see the link in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252113(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: but my data type is string for that column..as its value contains '02:05:00' type..

Comment: In that case I think you need to do calculation for total in sql query only and return sum of totals as another column "Total" along with existing 3 columns,  and then use this column in footer row as =(Fields!Total.Value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TimeStamp class gether with the Sum function, 
follow an example:

> =TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Sum(Fields!Dirigindo.Value))

Answer (score 0):

Try This out and see if it works

```
=(SUM(Cint(Split(Fields!WORKEDHOUR.value,":").GetValue(0))) + (SUM(Cint(Split(Fields!WORKEDHOUR.Value,":").GetValue(1))) + Sum(Cint(split(Fields!WORKEDHOUR.Value,":").GetValue(2)))\60)\60 ).ToString + ":" + ((SUM(Cint(Split(Fields!WORKEDHOUR.Value,":").GetValue(1))) + Sum(Cint(split(Fields!WORKEDHOUR.Value,":").GetValue(2)))\60) Mod 60).ToString + ":" + (Sum(Cint(split(Fields!WORKEDHOUR.Value,":").GetValue(2))) Mod 60).ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Facing the same issue here is your final answer.

    Step1: Go to your textbox expression and past below code
 =Code.MinutesToHoursMinutes(SUM(Hour(Fields!TTShortTime.Value)*60)+SUM(Minute(Fields!TTShortTime.Value)))    

        Step2: Goto your rdlc report properties => Tab Code, Here past below function       
        Function MinutesToHoursMinutes(ByVal vMins As Integer) As String
        Dim Mins As Integer
        Dim Hours As Integer
        vMins = IIF(vMins <= 0, 0, vMins)
        Hours = Floor(vMins / 60)
        Mins = vMins - (Hours * 60)
        MinutesToHoursMinutes = IIF(Hours < 9, "0" & CStr(Hours), CStr(Hours)) & ":" & IIF(Mins < 9, "0" & 
        CStr(Mins), CStr(Mins))
        Return MinutesToHoursMinutes
        End Function


    Here in Step1 we get hours and convert it into minutes then get minutes and sum with hour calculated minutes.
    then passes it to function which returns string format like hh:mm
```