# Summing time in RDLC report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, rdlc, timespan

In my RDLC report i am displaying times worked by employees.

I want to sum the time for each employee. I am returning the hours worked in a record set using a nullable timeSpan type and formatting them as hh:mm in the report as so:

```
7:30   
4:45  
5:30  
7:30  
7:30
```

There have been numerous other questions asked around the same issue [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740728/sum-time-hhmm-in-rdlc) ,  [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615063/sum-of-time-in-rdlc-report), but none seem to have an acceptable answer.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264878/need-help-in-sum-of-time-in-rdlc) is almost what i want. Except it shows day , hour , minute , second.
But my users want the total hours and minutes only, no days i.e. in this scenario i want to see 32 hours 45 minutes.

```
7:30   
4:45  
5:30  
7:30  
7:30

---------
Total:    32:45
```

I have tried the following formula, but i get a #error:

```
=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Sum(Fields!Hours.Value))
```

And :

```
=Sum(Fields!Hours.Value)
```

And this one gives me the days,hours,mins...so is close , but i need just total hh:mm:

```
=TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!Hours.Value))
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would try the parts as you can get them.

=(TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!Hours.Value)).Days * 24 + TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!Hours.Value)).Hours).ToString +":" +
TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!Hours.Value)).Minutes.ToString("d2")

The minutes in this case would have your :45, but the string formatting would have to allow for a single digit in hours as showing 2 digits, thus a possible leading zero if less than 10 minutes.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i needed. Thank you so much Drapp, this has been annoying me for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.. Worked for me.

`=IIf((SUM(Cint(Split(Fields!Call_Duration.value,":").GetValue(0))) + (SUM(Cint(Split(Fields!Call_Duration.Value,":").GetValue(1)))+    Sum(Cint(split(Fields!Call_Duration.Value,":").GetValue(2)))\60)\60 )    < 10,"0","" )    +(SUM(Cint(Split(Fields!Call_Duration.value,":").GetValue(0))) + (SUM(Cint(Split(Fields!Call_Duration.Value,":").GetValue(1)))+    Sum(Cint(split(Fields!Call_Duration.Value,":").GetValue(2)))\60)\60    ).ToString     +IIf(((SUM(Cint(Split(Fields!Call_Duration.Value,":").GetValue(1))) + Sum(Cint(split(Fields!Call_Duration.Value,":").GetValue(2)))\60) Mod    60) < 10,":0",":" )    + ((SUM(Cint(Split(Fields!Call_Duration.Value,":").GetValue(1))) + Sum(Cint(split(Fields!Call_Duration.Value,":").GetValue(2)))\60) Mod    60).ToString     +IIf((Sum(Cint(split(Fields!Call_Duration.Value,":").GetValue(2))) Mod 60) < 10,":0",":" )    + (Sum(Cint(split(Fields!Call_Duration.Value,":").GetValue(2))) Mod 60).ToString`

Comment: Bro, this is a post 6 years ago with a accepted answer. OP has most likely moved on.